# After mod_rewrite what to do with original pages?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I striped all my html extensions and can now visit both the one with the extension and the one without it.

Does google see having /example.php and /example as duplicate content now?

How would I make it so only the file without the html extension shows?

my code:

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: If you still publish .html links -- yes. All of your links should now be without html extension. Consider using `<link rel="canonical" href="PROPER_URL" />` -- this will definitely solve the duplicate content issue in eyes of Google and other search engines: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=link+rel+canonical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole concept of hiding existing files but still delivering them is kind of weird, but technically it would work like the following

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This does a redirect from `/example.html` to `/example` and returns a http status code 301 ("Moved permanently"). This tells e.g. google that the content of this page has moved.

Comment: What would be a better alternative to hide the extension from an existing page?

Comment: Technically this is a valid solution to hide the file extension, but the question is what the benefit of this is?

Comment: ok so if I do it like that I end up with a url path like this
'http://www.domain1.com/home/username/domains/domain1.com/public_html/xx/check' instead of pointing straight to http://www.domain1.com/xx/check do I need to set a base url, how?

Comment: Use `RewriteBase /`(directly after `RewriteEngine on`). -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase